# Time in 24 hour format showing in 12 hour format in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to print the time in 24-hour format as selected from the Time Picker method. However, every time I select a time that is in a 24-hour format, it somehow converts it into its 12-hour format. Let's say I selected 22:30 on the Time Picker Widget, it prints 10:30 instead of 22:30. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Here is my code:

```
TimeOfDay _toTime = TimeOfDay.now();
String closingTime = '';
    
InkWell(
 onTap: () => showTimePicker(
 context: context,
 initialTime: _toTime,
 builder: (context, child) => MediaQuery(
   data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
   alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
   child: child ?? Container()))
  .then((value) {
    setState(() {
      _toTime = value!;
      var dt = DateFormat('HH:mm').parse(_toTime.format(context));
      closingTime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dt);
      print('CLOSING TIME: $closingTime');
 });
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use a DateFormat instead of TimeOfDay, just include intl dependency

First parse the value to a date, then format it how you want

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime date= DateFormat.now();
// format date
print(DateFormat("HH:mm").format(date));
```

you can use different characters to achieve the result for example:

h        hour in am/pm (1~12)

H        hour in day (0~23)

k        hour in day (1~24)

K        hour in am/pm (0~11)

Refrence:

[Flutter dateformat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

[Intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

Comment: Your post does not answer my question as the initialValue in TimePicker only accepts a variable of type TimeOfDay and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```dart
  var dt = DateFormat('HH:mm').parse(_toTime.format(context));
```

is formatting the TimeOfDay to a String based on locale context,
then parsing this String to a DateTime according to the format HH:mm (24h). If your local context is 12h, this will behave as you say, converting it to AM.

TimeOfDay(22:30) -> "10:30 PM" -> 1970-01-01 10:30:00.000

If you want to print the value from the date picker to check, do that.

```
print('Picker returned: $value');
```

If you need it as a date, create the date directly.

```dart
final dt = DateTime(1970, 1, 1, _toTime.hour, _toTime.minute);
final dtString24h = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dt);
print('24h formatted dt: $dtString24h');
```